# Why this very simple cross domain jQuery AJAX is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am building a mobile application using the following technologies

- jQuery Mobile 1.4.4
- jQuery 2.1.1
- Cordova 3.6.3
- Testing this on Google Chrome 37 desktop version

** The True Solution**

If you are using jQuery 1.8 or later,

**Remember that .success, .error and .complete are deprecated in favor of .done, .fail and .always for jQuery 1.8 or higher**

**Remember to put the ajax defintion inside a $(document).ready() to make sure it runs after the DOM is fully ready**

**Chain the callback handlers like this: $.ajax().done().fail().always();**

Following is how I finally took care of it and I would not mind sharing it with anyone who wants to use ajax on jQuery Mobile, jQuery 1.8 or higher, PhoneGap, Cordova

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.4.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form>

<textarea name=userinput id=textarealol> </textarea>

<input type="button" value="Write on the server!" id="mybutton">

</form>

<script>

$mybutton = $("#mybutton");
$textarealol = $("#textarealol");

$( document ).ready(  
                    function( ) 
                    {

$hearitbutton.click(    
                        function(e) 
                        {                       
$.ajax(

{
    url     : "http://www.yourwebsite.com/yourpage.php",
    type    : "POST",
    data    : { comingover : $textarealol.val() },
}

    )
.done(

    function(e)
    {
        alert("Successfully Done");
    }
      )
.fail(

    function(e)
    {
        alert("ERRORNEOUS");
    }
      )
.always(

    function(e)
    {
       alert("E.N.D. jQ Ajax");
    }

      );

            } ); } );  // End of ready( ) and mybutton().click()

</script> </body> </html>
```

And then in your PHP file, the input will be stored in

```
$_POST['comingover']
```

Comment: I just ping'd the URL you listed above and got this error `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/engli237/public_html/cdajax/sweetsuck.php:2) in /home/engli237/public_html/cdajax/sweetsuck.php on line 4` Could it be that your server script has errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember it's JSONP which expects a callback so you need to return the callback function.

Something like this should work:

```
<?php
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

  $file = 'mytextfile.txt';
  $datvariable = $_POST['userinput'];
  file_put_contents($file, $lala , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX); // Nothing wrong with this

  $jsonp = false;
  // Get the name of the callback function
  if (isset($_POST['callback'])) {
    $_POST['callback'] = strip_tags($_POST['callback']);
    $jsonp = true;

    $pre  = $_POST['callback'] . '(';
    $post = ');';
  }

  // Replace ** some data if you want to ** with the data you wish to send to the
  // callback function.
  $json = json_encode( ** some data if you want to ** );
  print(($jsonp) ? $pre . $json . $post : $json);
?>
```

If you don't want to send any data with the callback then just return the callback without parameters:

```
  // $json = json_encode( ** some data if you want to ** ); // Remove this line.
  print(($jsonp) ? $pre . $post : '');
```

Comment: Well, `** some data if you want to **` should be replaced. That's just a container for the data (if any) you want to return with the callback function.